# How to put json-data into a list in flutter?

Tags: api, flutter, dart, weather

When I try to get data from this API https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/complete?lat=10&lon=10 it gets me a long array of some sort with all the timeseries. In the end, I would like to display some data from each time which has its own place in the downloaded array. I want to covert all data to a list so I can manipulate the data but i get errors like these type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String.
This is my code

```
List<dynamic> timeseriesglobal = [];
  void loadForecast() async{

    //Getting the data from API
    Response response = await get("https://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/2.0/complete?lat=57.047218&lon=9.920100");

    var results = jsonDecode(response.body);

timeseriesglobal = results["properties"]["timeseries"] as List;


  }
```

And in the end i have this code for displaying the data

```
child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: timeseriesglobal.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    return Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          timeseriesglobal[index]
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide the property name that you want to show Ex time

```
ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: timeseriesglobal.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    return Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          timeseriesglobal[index]['time']
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Create Your BaseModel from the json you are getting from the link.
Then Parse like below

var data=  BaseModel.fromJson(response.body);

Now this will contain everything and you can extract whatever u want from the model
To convert the json use [this link](https://app.quicktype.io/)